# S6 edge doesn't vibrate

Tags: vibration, samsung-galaxy-s-6-edge+

For some reason, my device (Samsung Galaxy S6 edge) doesn't vibrate. At all. I downloaded an app with the only intent of vibrating (an app that just vibrates the device), but it doesn't. This doesn't just apply to the app I downloaded (it was a test case), it affects every app that tries to vibrate. For some reason, it doesn't vibrate through any apps. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Try checking power saving mode options ("toggle" turn off power saving and reboot) or start the phone on safe mode and see if problems persist

Comment: Tried that, still didn't work